# Unity: Game Over screen - show stats w/ restart and leaderboards

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, unityscript

For the last three days I've been fiddling about with a game over screen for my game (which is sooo close to finished!), but haven't been able to come up with the result I want. So far I have a screen that says game over and  shows the total score and how many kills the player got. But I also want two buttons, one for restarting the game and one for showing the leaderboards (once that's implemented).

I want something simple, for example like Jetpack Joyride or Flappy Bird;

Can someone please show me an example code of how to do this? I want it to appear when the game is over (my code for this is `if ( gameOver == true );` ). Every one of my attempts so far have either crashed the game or messed with the rest of my code...

I'm creating a game for android and coding in Unityscript.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You would need to implement a GUI system that handles what is being viewed. For example, in one of my games I have a game over screen and it will only show if I set my gamestate to game over:

```
public enum CameraState
{
    CS_PreGame, CS_NodeSelect, CS_Player, CS_Ball, CS_EndGame
}

public enum GameState
{
    GS_MenuSelect, GS_NodeSelect, GS_Swing, GS_BallInAir, GS_BallLanded, GS_EndGame
}
```

Here you're initializing 2 enums that will represent a State Machine for your game...

You then make instances of those...

```
public CameraState cam_State;
public GameState game_State;
```

Then in the start you would probably want to set the state to the first state you want, as so:

```
cam_State = CameraState.CS_PreGame;
```

And then you would have a Coroutine that handles whatever behavior you want in that state, as so:

```
IEnumerator CS_PreGame()
{
    DisableOtherCams (PreGameCam);

    yield return 0;
}
```

This is in C#, but none of it is syntax-special so you can do this exact thing in Javascript.

If you're still confused then a simple way to look at it is whenever you want the game to go in game over, just set the state to game over there, make your coroutine, and add the behaviors in there. Set a bool, and in an ONGui() function have it display a menu ONLY if the bool is true (set bool to true when the game state is game over)

```
void OnGUI()
    {
        if (showGUI) {
            // Main Menu Options
            if (currentMenu == "main")
                MainMenu();
            else if (currentMenu == "credits")
                Credits();
            else if (currentMenu == "exit")
                Exit();
    }
```

Restarting game is simple, Just load the first level (Application.LoadLevel(0)), leaderboards you will have to do yourself but you would have some type of GUI that displays information from a database, or if you hardcode it then that.